# How to make this function dynamic in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

What I want is for it to accept this function

```
function (x1,y1,x2, y2,x3, y3, x4, y4, xToCheck, yToCheck, Allowance);
```

This is the possible combination for `var x` and `var y`

```
var x1 = x1 - x2;
var y1 = y1 - y2;
var x2 = x2 - x3;
var y2 = y2 - y3;
var x3 = x3 - x4;
var y3 = y3 - y4;
var x4 = x2 - x4;
var y4 = y2 - y4;
var x5 = x1 - x3;
var y5 = y1 - y3;
```

Note: The function above can only accept one set of `var` which is `var x1` and `var y1`, what I want is to make my function more dynamic so that it can accept the other set of `var`.

Comment: *"What I want is for it to accept this function"* - Huh?

Comment: What I want is to make it dynamic

Comment: Your need is not clear at all !

Comment: Do you mean you want optional default values for the sent variables???

Comment: @newuser1 added an answer to explain one possible way to make some input values optional.

Answer (score 0):

Your "allowance" (tolerance) should be on the distance point-line. See how to calculate it:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the function to take an undetermined/dynamic set of coordinates `x1, y1 ... xn, yn`?

Then you could use a single argument (an array or object) for all the coordinates, like this:

```
ST.PT.isMouseOnLine = function (points, xToCheck, yToCheck, Allowance) {}
```

Then pass an array of points:

```
ST.PT.isMouseOnLine([ {x: 10, y:10}, { x:20, y:30}, { x:30, y:10} ], 15, 15, 10 );
```

so you can iterate over the `points` array and do the checks for every point.

Comment: can you have a demo of the codes above? I will really appreciate it.

Comment: @newuser1 I'm not really sure this is what you're asking for, just guessing. If my guess is correct I could provide more details, but first you should clearly define your problem. WHY do you want the function to accept more arguments? What's the current result, and what is the expected result after modifications?

Comment: I want my function to accept more arguments so that it can process the whole set of var which in the code above does not process.

Answer (score 0):

Do You mean, the count of arguments is variable?
I think you just use a array type argument.
Like this:

```
function (xs,ys, xToCheck, yToCheck, Allowance){
    var newxs,newys;
    newxs[0]=xs[0]-xs[1];//compute newxs,newys from xs,ys
    ...
}
```

And use some algorithm to compute newxs from xs and ys.
Like this:

```
//just a example,it's not correct
for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    newxs[i]=xs[i]-xs[i+1];
    newys[i]=ys[i]-ys[i+1];
    ...
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate more

Comment: In fact , I'm not sure what you want.
Maybe you elaborate first.

Answer (score 0):

If you want optional default values for the sent variables - as you mentioned in the comment - then use this structure:

Let say we want `xToCheck, yToCheck, Allowance` to be optional:

```
ST.PT.isMouseOnLine = function (x1, y1, x2, y2, _xToCheck, _yToCheck, _Allowance)   {

    //Get the variables:
    xToCheck = _xToCheck || 5; //replace value with default value or variable.
    yToCheck = _yToCheck || 5; //same
    Allowance = _Allowance || 0; //same

    //Calculate:
    var x = x1 - x2;
    var y = y1 - y2;
    var m = y / x;

    /* rest of your code */
}
```

Note that the assignment `variable = var1 || var2` means if `var1` is undefined then set equals to `var2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) Object to iterate over all arguments passed to your function. This way, you can simply remove the last 3 arguments (xToCheck, yToCheck and Allowance) and iterate over the resulting values to fill the dynamic X and Y arrays, like this:

```
function arbitraryArguments() {
    // first, convert function arguments into an array
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

    // then get the last 3 arguments, which are always present
    var
        Allowance = args.pop(),
        yToCheck  = args.pop(),
        xToCheck  = args.pop(),
        x         = [],
        y         = [];

    // ... and fill-in the X and Y arrays from what's left
    for (var i in args) {
        if (i % 2) {
            y.push(args[i]);
        } else {
            x.push(args[i]);
        }
    }

    // ... do whatever you need with all the X and Y values
    //     in these x and y arrays

    for (var a in x) {
        console.log('x' + a + ' = ' + x[a]);
        console.log('y' + a + ' = ' + y[a]);
    }

    console.log('Allowance = ' + Allowance);
    console.log('yToCheck = ' + yToCheck);
    console.log('xToCheck = ' + xToCheck);
}

arbitraryArguments(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 111, 222, 1010);
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tz1t6cmn/

Comment: the `arbitraryArguments()` function is just a rewrite of your own `ST.PT.isMouseOnLine()` function with its functionality removed (replaced by the "// ... do whatever you need with all the X and Y values in these x and y array" comment)

Comment: fyi, JavaScript knowledge is required to apply the principles of JavaScript and StackOverflow is not a place to find free developer force to do this for you - our answers are trying to help you move forward, not code your program for you